# text inserted at end of minipage environment within figure

Tags: minipage, subcaption

It seems that there is something wrong with my minipage as it looks like there is a "b" being inserted in my figure. The minipage is contained within the figure.

When compiled, a letter "b" is placed by my "here1" (which I added for purposes of debugging).
When I add a `%` to comment out directly after the last `\end{subfigure}` the "b" remains in the same position, but the "here1" moves to the right side of the minipage. When I do not have "here1" and "here2" in my code, the "b" remains.

**NOTE**: Even when I change figure b's caption to "image d", there "b" still appears, not a "d".

So my question is:
**Why is this "b" being placed in my figure?**

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5 paper, 4pt]{article}
\usepackage{float, subcaption, graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth, height=8cm]{example-image-a}}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.55\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \usebox{\mybox}
        \caption{image a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[\ht\mybox]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{image b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vfil
        \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{image c}
        \end{subfigure}
        here1
    \end{minipage}
    here2
    \caption{many pics}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here's the document/figure **without** the `%` added after the `\end{subfigure}`
[image: what the figure looks like without commenting out after the end of the subfigure]

And here's what the figure looks like **with** the `%` added so that the last `\end{subfigure}` -> `\end{subfigure}%`[image: figure with % added to cut whitespace]

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[\ht\mybox]` that option should be `[t]` or `[c]` or `[b]`

Comment: `minipage` has indeed an option height argument, but only if you also have at least two optional arguments. Correct would be either `\begin{minipage}[<pos>]{<widht>}` or `\begin{minipage}[<pos>][<height>]{<width>}` or `\begin{minipage}[<pos>][<height>][<innerpos>]{<width>}` but NOT `\begin{minipage}[<height>]{<width>}`.

Comment: Thanks to you both, this fixed it.